# Feedly does not download items in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have Feedly app installed in my Google Chrome browser, and it worked without a hitch until recently. All of a sudden it stopped to download any feed item and shows just a blank page instead.

Tried:

- Disable other extensions
- Reinstall the app

What can it be? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem.

But

> Chrome>setting>extensions>Feedly - News, Blogs and Youtube
>
> Option>click
>
> Load feedly over HTTPS>no>yes
>
> save

solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but it is not my case :(

Comment: Thank you jonsca! Possibly Google Chrome browser not stable beta? α?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again! Nope, my Google is on stable channel. I have solved the issue by a strange trick. Trying to find out what was the reason of the issue I have bumped into the [thread](https://getsatisfaction.com/feedly/topics/cant_login_to_feedly). Tried all suggestions from there - nope :(( Nobody could help, so I have continued by myself. I found out Feedly does not show up in any of browsers (FF, Opera), so I have tried it on safari Iphone/other PC - and yep it works. So I have just tried it on my windows guest account on Chrome - yep works. The bottom line - I do not know what was the reason but as a workaround - just set up a new Windows account and that is just it. With the trick I solved the toughest ticket I had for months from [Google](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/infinite-redirect-loop-after-search-performing-from-google-search-box-in-google). I hope it helps some folks.